# How can I do a timer with Ionic?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, web-applications

I'm trying to do a sort of timer in my Ionic application, It should start when I load the page and it should add a value every second to a variable previously initialized to 0.
I wrote this but it doesn't work:

```
  ngOnInit() {
 this.counter();
}


counter(){
  while(this.value!=1){
    timer(1000).subscribe(x => {this.value=this.value+0.075 })
  }
}
```

timer is a method imported from 'rxjs'.

The piece of HTML that must change during the time is:

```
<ion-progress-bar value={{value}} buffer={{buffer}}></ion-progress-bar>
```

And the variables are define here:

```
    private value_: number=0;
    private buffer_: number=this.value;
```

Finally I would like to say that I have already created the set and get methods.

Comment: Maybe you really need [interval](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/interval)?

Comment: The timer should stop after 10 minutes but for now i used random numbers

Comment: your `while` block won't execute when `this.value` is not 1 (or true)

Comment: Thanks @R.Richards I'm reading interval but I don't realy understand how can I use it

Comment: you're right @MikeS. I'm a fool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You don't actually need the subscription in the controller. You could use `async` pipe in template.
2. You could start the timer immediately with initial delay set to zero: `timer(0, 1000)`.
3. Instead of `while` you could use `takeWhile` operator to complete the observable.

**Controller**

```js
import { timer, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { map, takeUntil, takeWhile } from 'rxjs/operators';

private stop$ = new Subject<any>();

private value_: number = 0;
private buffer_: number = this.value;

timer$ = timer(0, 1000).pipe(
  takeUntil(this.stop$),               // stop when `stop$` emits
  takeWhile(_ => this.value_ < 1),     // are you sure `this.value_ == 1` is right?
  finalize(() => this.someMethod()),   // run this method when observable completes
  map(_ => {
    this.value_ = this.value_ + 0.075;
    return this.value_;
  }
);
```

**Template**

```html
// is buffer always set to zero?
<ion-progress-bar [value]="timer$ | async" [buffer]="buffer"></ion-progress-bar>
```

#### Update

1. Use `finalize` operator to do something when the observable completes.
2. Use `takeUntil` operator to stop the observable stream anytime. In this case I've used a RxJS `Subject` called `stop$`. When you wish to stop the stream, push to it like `this.stop$.next()`.
3. If you wish to run `finalize` only using `takeWhile`, then move the `takeUntil` operator below `finalize`. The `someMethod()` won't be triggered when you explicitly stop the stream.

Comment: I import the functions and it says me:
  Overload 1 of 3, '(predicate: (value: number, index: number) => value is number): OperatorFunction<number, number>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: number, index: number) => value is number'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(predicate: (value: number, index: number) => boolean, inclusive?: boolean): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<number>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: number, index: number) => boolean'

Comment: Did you import `takeWhile`? I've made 2 changes to the code: 1. Import `takeWhile`. 2. Pass a callback function to `takeWhile`. Please try the changes again.

Comment: How can I run a method when value is 1?

Comment: And how can I stop it?

Comment: You can run a method using `finalize` operator. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks thanks thanks thanks. I have no other words